# Removal of FBML

Tags: authentication, facebook-fbml

1

I am wondering if I need to provide any changes if currently I am using on my page just Facebook Login button with code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {FB.init({ appId: #FBApplicationID#', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true}); FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {if (response.status === 'connected') {raisepostback();}
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
        ...            
           }); /* end FB.init */ 
        }; /* end window.fbAsyncInit */
       window.fbAsyncInit(); </script>
<div><fb:login-button scope="email,user_about_me,user_likes, user_birthday" size="large" length="long" ></fb:login-button></div>
```

Will it work after June 1, 2012? 
Please advise.

Thank you, 
         Peter.

Comment: Yes it will, since it's JavaScript and not FBJS, so it have nothing to do with FBML deprecation.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. But what about "xfbml: true"? Should I leave it?

Comment: Yes, because of `fb:login-button` which is XFBML

Answer (score 0):

As Juicy Scripter mentioned in the [comments](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10110250/removal-of-fbml#comment12954184_10110250), the removal of FBML will not affect your code.

XFBML is different from FBML.

All social plugins and SDK utilizing XFBML are perfectly valid to use after June.